# Spring MVC BindingResult rejectValue value persists

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a change password page which has 3 fields in modelObject.
1. oldPassword 2. newPassword 3. newConfirmPassword

`<spring:bind path="oldPassword">
      <form:password path="oldPassword"/>
      <c:if test="${status.error}">${status.errorMessage}</c:if>
   </spring:bind>`

another 2 such lines for newPassword and newConfirmPassword

And in Controller, 
(BindingResult result, Model model,@ModelAttribute("modelObject") ChangePassword modelObject)

`result.rejectValue("newPassword", "errorMessage", "some message");
     modelObject.setOldPassword(null);
     modelObject.setNewPassword(null);
     modelObject.setNewConfirmPassword(null);
     model.addAttribute("modelObject", modelObject);`

On error display, except for newPassword, all other values are cleared.
I have to clear the rejected value also while return the error message, for security issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

are you setting modelObject.setNewPassword(null)?, when you do error display.
i see only setOldPassword and setNewConfirmPassword set to null,

Comment: Yes, setNewPassword(null) is being used. While returning back model object to same view (jsp) from the controller, only input box of name="newPassword" is filled, but not others.

Comment: what is the issue? you said except newPassword all other fields are cleared so i said to check whether you set newpassword = null while returing back. also check whether you inputbox name value matches with the Model object name setter method.